# Find incomplete TCP connection (SYN but no FIN) using Wireshark

Tags: tcp, wireshark

I am using Wireshark to capture packets on my computer. My goal is to capture for a short period of time and find a connection that was never completed, i.e., the connection would begin while the capture is ongoing but would not complete before the capture ends.

Specifically, I want to find a connection that has a SYN packet in the capture but no corresponding FIN packet. Is there a filter or method that can be applied to accomplish this?

Comment: If you just want to see this in action, start a download of a large file. This will make sure you know the remote address and port. Then filter all communication that happen with that IP + Port.

Comment: This question has been asked before on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/q/402322